# Git fetch tagged file without cloning

Tags: git

Concerning these URLs:

```
git://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git
http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/tags
```

How do I, say, the MANIFEST from perl-5.10.0?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to grab a single file from a Git repository (using a Git client) right now.  However, as noted by Manni, the files can be downloaded using a web client if the repository is exposed that way.

There are patches under development to add a `sparse checkout` feature to Git, but it is not yet complete.

See the [Git mail list](http://dir.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git) for details.  The latest info (that I could find) is [here](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/131026/match=sparse+checkout).

Answer (score 2):

If the the server will process [*git archive*](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-archive.html) requests (it is [disabled by default for *git daemon*](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-daemon.html#_services), but it seems to be on for `git://perl5.git.perl.org`):

```
git archive --remote=git://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git --format=tar \
    perl-5.10.0 MANIFEST | tar -xOf - >MANIFEST-5.10.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Direct your browser to http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blob_plain/HEAD:/MANIFEST.
​​​​​

Comment: the question is how to do it using GIT